# React Router doesn't encode ampersands but encodes spaces in path params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm having an issue with react router encoding spaces but not ampersands. So `localhost:8080/you & me` is encoded to be `localhost:8080/you%20&%20me` instead of `localhost:8080/you%20%26%20me` and I'm using a wonky hack to decode then re-encode everything. I was wondering if anyone can recommend a better solution.

Comment: I'd use slugs (`you-me`) instead, but not sure if it's possible for you.

Comment: You could use the [slug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slug) nom module to do this for you if you need this as a path parameter. However, I think it's a route URL and not a path parameter.

Comment: agree with @EmileBergeron you shouldn't be using special characters in the URL. Lets say you are loading a list of elements that is paginated. You would request like this `some.api/my/get/route?page=2&rows=20` The `?` and `=` and `&` are reserved for url parameters. You should rethink how to define your routes where you dont need special characters (non alphanumeric).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not use non-alphanumeric characters in the URL. Some characters like `&`, `/`, `?`, and `=` have special meanings in URLs. Even though `react-router` does not throw an error when you create a route component with a `&` in the url, as you have noticed, you'll end up with wonky behavior. It's best practice to avoid strange edge cases. You can read more about allowed characters in a url [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/498/which-special-characters-are-safe-to-use-in-url).

As a workaround, you can achieve nearly the same URL with `localhost:8080/you-and-me`. This is a safe url without spaces and special characters. It's also human readable, which anything with spaces wouldn't be easily readable as it would be encoded.